# why does redirecting with an instance variable take you to a show view(Log-in)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord, instance-variables

How does the following piece of code `redirect_to @user`in my create action know how to redirect to my show view?

I don't get how it would possibly know this. I know this is a newb question but I just can't understand why @user works. It would make sense if it was something like redirect 'show' but why is @user used?

Here is my controller code:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)   
    if @user.save
      flash[:success] = "Welcome to the Sample App!"
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  private

    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password,
                                   :password_confirmation)
    end
end
```

Comment: Post your routes.It could help to explain a bit more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
redirect_to @user
```

is the short hand for:

```
redirect_to user_path(@user)
```

You can either use the long-hand or the short-hand. They will both work the same way.

by convention, `redirect_to @user` maps to:

```
GET  /users/:id(.:format)    users#show
```

That's how it knows to redirect you to the `show` page.

The `show` action is the only one (to my knowledge) that has a short-cut.

If you do `rake routes`, you'll see the complete map:

```
user_path    GET     /users/:id(.:format)    users#show
```

Answer (score 2):

If you run `rake routes`, you will able to see this `route` which is referring to `users#show`

```
GET /users/:id  users#show
```

In your case `redirect_to @user` which is equivalent of

`redirect_to :action => 'show', :id => @user` which matches the `/users/:id` convention

**OR**

It can also written as `redirect_to user_path(@user)` which also returns `/users/:id`

So,the controller just ends up redirecting to the `show` page.

These **[Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resource-routing-the-rails-default)** will help you understand in detail.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Infact in syntax

```
redirect_to @user
```

@user variable here gives you the id of that user and if you see your routes (using rake routes) you would see a route users/:id which exactly maps to users#show. So that why it goes to show method or users controller.

You can change this functionality if you want to. There are two approaches to it, a good one and a bad one.

First approach is:
 Change you routes which maps users/:id to some other action of your controller

Second bad approach is to redirect to some other path within show action of users controller.

Hope this explanation is enough for your understanding

Answer (score 0):

When you `redirect_to` an object in Rails (which is what you're doing), the framework has a lot of built-in functionality to take care of things for you

One of these in-built features is the ability to detect & redirect to the object itself

---

**Objects**

When you pass `@user`, you are passing a singular object, which Rails takes as meaning that you want to go to the `show` view (you want to view the object, right?)

You need to remember that Ruby / Rails is Object Orientated. You're calling them `@instance variables`, but really they are objects. Those objects contain a lot more data than your standard data - they contain information from the model & db

This means that if you build your `@instance variable` in the conventional Rails way (using `Model` data), you're going to get an object

--

**Login**

It seems to me that you're redirecting to the `@user` object. However, I would imagine this will be covnered by your authentication system, hence why you're receiving the `login` page

---

To fix this, you should try redirecting to specific paths, like this:

```
redirect_to users_path
```

Answer (score 0):

Everyone has pointed out that controller interprets

```
redirect_to @user or redirect_to user_path(@user)
```

as

```
GET  /users/:id(.:format)    users#show
```

Question arises how Rails comes to know that out of so many routes it needs to go on to users#show

[image]

As you can see in above image that 3 paths are associated with
user_path & it requires id which you have passed using @user

So now controller ask which HTTP method **GET/PATCH/PUT/DELETE**

Since we have not specified any method it will automatically consider GET method & result is

```
users#show
```